# Worklight - require.js does not load modules on iPad2 iOS device

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, requirejs, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a mobile app (Worklight 6.0.1) using require.js and I can successfully execute it on Mobile Browser Simulator and even in iOS XCode simulator but it does not work when deployed on iPad2 iOS 7.0.4 device.
My guess is that there is some conflicts between requre.js and the cordova which comes with Worklight since the code in global scope is executed but not the ones in require modules.

Comment: Cordova is also part of the app you're running in the simulator, so...  does not sound related. Add more information, like: logs, error messages, code snippets...

Comment: There is no error in the XCode output. I've also opened the Safari dev tool and the console is empty.

Comment: start adding alerts in key functions in your code and see when and where it fails.

Comment: Like I said, the global scope code is executed (I noticed this with alerts) but the code in require(...) functions is not executed - the alerts in this scope are not reached.

Comment: Can you produce a very minimal demo project exhibiting the problem and upload to dropbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was writing a filename wrongly: filelogger vs fileLogger. Also I've discovered that some JS files referred in require/define functions did not exist anymore - removed them previously. This error appeared only when deploying on the actual device (in the iOS simulator the application executed correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the require() call after deviceready event has been fired by Cordova?

Comment: In Worklight you should not check the deviceready event - this is what wlCommonInit function is for. When code from thus function is executed it means that the Worklight framework and Cordova have fully initialized - the deviceready check is done internally by Worklight.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with "RequireJS + Cordova" is throughly described here https://www.nothing.ch/en/research/using-optimised-requirejs-combination-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your issue was surely related with the "filelogger" vs "fileLogger" caps mismatch.

It worked on the simulator because incredibly, the simulators for apple devices are not case sensitive, but the actual devices are. Has happened a couple of times to me that resources load perfectly on simulator but do not load on an actual device.